# Gaussian curvature of a parallel surface

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

**Question 11 section 3.5 in Do Carmo part c.**

Let a surfae $x$ have constant mean curvature equal to $c$ does not equal $0$ and consider the parallel surface to x at a distance $\dfrac{1}{2c}$.  Prove that this parallel surface has constant Gaussian curvature equal to $4c^2$.

I have proved earlier parts of the question that the Gaussian curvature of a parallel surface is $$\frac{K}{1-2Ha+Ka^2}$$

However I am running into calculation errors with part $c$. Any help is appreciated, as I'm just practicing for my upcoming final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the answer to your question is easy: If you substitute $a=\dfrac1{2c}$ and $H=c$ into your equation, you get
$$\frac K{1-2aH+a^2K} = \frac K{1-1+a^2K} = \frac1{a^2}=4c^2.$$

But be warned: The sign of $H$ depends on the parametrization of your surface (e.g., if you switch $u$ and $v$, the direction of the outward normal $N$ changes, and the sign of $H$ changes). So the "distance" of the parallel surface needs to be a *signed* distance. For example, with a sphere of radius $r$ with the usual *outward*-pointing normal, the principal curvatures are $-1/r$ and the mean curvature is $c=-1/r$. If you consider the parallel surface at distance $a$, this means you follow the normal a distance of $a$, which means your radius is now $r+a$, so the new principal curvatures are $-1/(r+a)$. But doCarmo wants you to use $a=\dfrac1{2c} = -\dfrac r2$, so we get $K=\left(-\dfrac1{r+a}\right)^2 = \left(-\dfrac1{r/2}\right)^2 = \dfrac4{r^2} = 4c^2$.

Comment: Nice answer- I had made a silly mistake in my calculation. That insight was also quite useful!